# on click handler has additional params

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this line of code and i don't know what it does:

```
$("body").on("click", "#my_info_box, a.submitSomething", function(){
            doSomething();
        });
```

Comment: It's called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), you can do more research on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets an event handler for clicking the element with `#my_info_box` and elements having `.submitSomething`. The handler is the `function() { doSomething(); }`

Answer (score 0):

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

More found here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

It does event delegation. It means that jQuery will listen for changes inside the `#my_info_box` box that might happen with AJAX and will still work on the new data. Otherwise it cannot know new data was loaded with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

1. First parameter is for event for track.
2. Second is for additional selector([Event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events))
3. Third is for callback function.

So simply: `.on()` is an alternative for `.click()`. But it works also for dynamically created elements.